# How to determine if a grammar is suitable for top down parsing?

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction

I have been reading top down parsing from dragon book recently and one of questions asks to check if the given grammar is suitable for top down parsing or not. How to determine this? Are the following conditions for the grammar sufficient to be a valid one?

> 1) Left factored. 
> 2) No Left Recursion. 
> 3) Unambiguous.

Comment: Is this a practical or theoretical question? The grammar in the C99 standard is left-recursive and ambiguous, but GCC uses a top-down recursive-descent parser.

Comment: This is a theoretical question

Answer (score 1):

A grammar that uses the leftmost derivation, is unambiguous, and has no left recursion is known as an LL(k) language. k is the amount of look-ahead used by the parser. Top down parsing uses LL(k) languages, so if the language is LL it should be top-down parsable.

sources: 
http://www.csd.uwo.ca/~moreno/CS447/Lectures/Syntax.html/node14.html
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-down_parsing

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As per [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compiler_design/compiler_design_top_down_parser.htm) top down parser is superset of LL parser. So what is the condition for a grammar to be eligible to be a top down parser?

Comment: Since it is a superset it has all the capabilities to parse an LL language, which is the language you have described. The question you asked was "Are the following conditions for the grammar sufficient to be a valid one?". Because a top down parser parses LL grammars, the conditions are sufficient.